# A new entity was found through the relationship *** that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, copy, fixtures

I'm currently creating some fixtures for some tests and i faced this error. Have you an idea about how to solve it ?

I've so many fixtures to copy paste it.

```
A new entity was found through the relationship '***' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: 
***. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on     
this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the 
mapping for example @OneToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find 
out which entity causes the problem implement '***#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that there is a related entity in a current object that has not been saved to the database yet. You either need to make sure your relationship is set to cascade persist calls (meaning it will save this automatically) or you need to persist the unsaved entity before saving the current entity.

Comment: I don't want to implement this cascade feature. And this entity is a fixtures already saved in DB... so it's already persisted...

Comment: Paul is right, this error occurs with entities unknown to the entitymanager. If you say that the objects are already saved in the database, then somehow they most have become detached. Perhaps you save them in the session and retrieve them in a later call?

Comment: @EmanuelOster This is exactly true in my case with session. How could one get rid of this wrong error?