# Symfony2 ManyToMany relation save also the existent related entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony-2.8

I'm facing to a problem with a Doctrine ManyToMany entities relations on Symfony2.8.
I have entity Trip which can be composed of many Experience entities.

Here's my Trip definition:

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Trip
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="trip")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\TripRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Trip
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Timestampable\Timestampable;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;    

    // other fields

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Experience", inversedBy="trips")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="experience_trip",
     *  joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="trip_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="experience_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $experiences;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->experiences = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // other setters and getters

    /**
     * Add experience
     *
     * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Experience $experience
     *
     * @return Trip
     */
    public function addExperience(\MyBundle\Entity\Experience $experience)
    {
        $this->experiences[] = $experience;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove experience
     *
     * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Experience $experience
     */
    public function removeExperience(\MyBundle\Entity\Experience $experience)
    {
        $this->experiences->removeElement($experience);
    }

    /**
     * Get experiences
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getExperiences()
    {
        return $this->experiences;
    }

}
```

On the other side I have the Experience entity:

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Experience
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="experience")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\ExperienceRepository")
 */
class Experience
{

    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;
    use ORMBehaviors\Timestampable\Timestampable;


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Trip", mappedBy="experiences")
     */
    private $trips;

    // other fields

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->trips = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // other setters and getters

    /**
     * Add trip
     *
     * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Trip $trip
     *
     * @return Experience
     */
    public function addTrip(\MyBundle\Entity\Trip $trip)
    {
        $this->trips[] = $trip;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove trip
     *
     * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Trip $trip
     */
    public function removeTrip(\MyBundle\Entity\Trip $trip)
    {
        $this->trips->removeElement($trip);
    }

    /**
     * Get trips
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTrips()
    {
        return $this->trips;
    }
}
```

In controller, the user can generate a new Trip, putting the object in session to recall it until the real association.

```
/**
 * @Route("/add-experience", name="add_experience")
 */
public function addExperienceAction(Request $request)
{
    $experienceId = $request->query->get('experience');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $experience = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Experience')->find($experienceId);
    if (!$experience || !get_class($experience) == 'MyBundle:Experience') {
        $response = array("message" => "Experience not found", "success" => false);

        return new Response(json_encode($response));
    }

    $session = $request->getSession();
    $trip = $session->get('trip');
    // This service only construct parameters
    $searchParameters = $this->get('mybundle.search')->buildSearchParameters();
    if (!$trip) {
        $trip = new Trip();
        $trip->setStartDate($searchParameters['startDate']);
        $trip->setEndDate($searchParameters['endDate']);
    }

    $trip->addExperience($experience);
    $trip->setClient($this->getUser()); /** user can be null */
    $em->persist($trip);
    $em->flush();

    $session->set('trip', $trip);

    $response = array("message" => "Experience n.$experienceId added correctly", "success" => true);

    return new Response(json_encode($response));
}
```

The problem.
At first call, it work like a charm, add the experience_trip entry and all it's ok.
At second call, with a different experiece, persisting of trip is looking for a cascade on experience entity, throwing error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'MyBundle\Entity\Trip#experiences' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: . To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

This because is trying to add a new Experience entity, in fact, using `cascade={"persist"}`, generate a sql exception on experience duplication, due to uniqueness on a field.

Same model is correctly managed by the Sonata TripAdmin class, without trying to add a new experience at trip persisting, than avoiding to create an ExperienceTrip entity. In the experience_trip table i can correctly see the correct association.

Why saving trip, the second time it try to insert a new experience?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions by myself, thanks also to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373891/a-new-entity-was-found-through-the-relationship-that-was-not-configured-to-c#comment68003301_40374114).

The entity in the session is, for some reason, detached and is not a valid entity. So persist try to add it again.

Comment: In particular: $trip = $session->get('trip'); need to be followed by something like $trip = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Trip')->find($trip->getId());